# Correct use of ergeben?

Tags: translation

In playing a card game, I’d like to say that taking a certain card results in negative points. Is it correct to say ‘diese Karte ergibt Minuspunkte?’

Answer (score 8):

As a board gamer, the wordings

> Diese Karte bringt Minuspunkte
>   Diese Karte bringt einem Minuspunkte ein

sound most natural to me

Comment: *Einbringen* sounds a little outdated to me.

Comment: It might be *a little* outdated for general use, but in gaming context it is quite normal.

Answer (score 6):

The word "ergeben" can refer to the result of a calculation, but the card is just one component of the calculation, together with the points before. I think it is understandable, but it sounds a little strange.

To what game are you referring?

Comment: Thank you!   I understand your point - that really helps me to appreciate the situation where one might use ergeben.  The game I was thinking about is a card game called Sticheln.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds clumsy. There are better ways to phrase what you want:

> Bei dieser Karte erhält man Minuspunkte / einen Minuspunkt.

*this could also be written in an instructions manual*

> Diese Karte gibt einem Minuspunkte / einen Minuspunkt.
>   Von dieser Karte bekommt man Minuspunkte / einen Minuspunkt.
>   Bei dieser Karte kriegt man Minuspunkte / einen Minuspunkt.

*These sound a little colloquial, use them when talking with your friends, not necessarily in your game instructions, although it wouldn't be terribly bad.*

Comment: Is there any special meaning intended with the italics?

Comment: Thank you!  I like you first suggestion a lot.

Answer (score 6):

Without more context (is it a game with tricks, a card trading game, ...) it is difficult, to come up with a specific proposal. A quite generic one is:

> Für diese Karte bekommt man (x) Punkte abgezogen.